# Does SELinux file relabelling start anew if it is interrupted during boot phase?

Tags: selinux

SELinux relabelling can continue very long during boot phase. What happens when this process is interrupted by yet another boot? Does SELinux start relabelling from the beginning if it could not finish it on the previous boot or does it remember where it left off to only continue from where it was interrupted?